# Notification from Facebook for App - This account has enhanced targeting data set to off

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently created an app on developers.facebook.com to learn OAuth using OpenFB. I got it working but from yesterday I've been getting a notification message written below in my facebook app account - to be frank I don't understand what they are trying to say. Can anyone please shed some light?

> This account has enhanced targeting data set to off. We are removing the opt out setting, effective October 15. Note that data received through the use of our pixel and mobile app events has not been used for targeting to date, and we do not have plans to do so beyond small-scale tests. If we start using this data to improve ad targeting, we will ensure that this data makes up only a small percentage of the inputs into each targeting segment. You can also remove the Facebook pixel, app events and Social Plugins from your websites and apps before the effective date.

Comment: They are just telling you that in the future, apps will not be able to opt-out of Facebook gathering “enhanced targeting data” any more, but that Facebook will gather data for any apps that use features where this might apply to. See also http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/opt-websites-apps-out-enhanced-targeting-data/439613 – _opting out_ of that as this article describes, will not be possible any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, Facebook can collect data about what a user does on your app/site to build a more dynamic profile of that individual, and target them better.

This article does a good job of explaining what it is *- note: the article is from when the advanced targeting data collection first started to roll out.*

http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/06/12/us-facebook-ads-idUSKBN0EN0U520140612

Comment: Thanks.. Now it makes some sense